# Slick jQuery Image Carousel Not Loading At All

Tags: jquery

I cannot for the life of me work out why the slick jQuery code I am using will not work. I have followed the instructions word for word but am clearly missing something!

I have a test page at http://www.helidronesurveys.co.uk/index2.html

I have a feeling its something to do with the linking of the CSS/jQuery files but I'm not sure.

The slider I'm trying to use is: http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/

Comment: http://www.helidronesurveys.co.uk/slick/slick.min.js not found! You can see the errors in Chrome Inspector. There are 4 as of now().

Comment: Also this: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'width' of undefined (lightbox.js:106)` may break your JS.

Comment: fixed that but still not working :( I'm not too worried about errors in lightbox.js as that's working perfectly fine.

Comment: Do you think the lightbox.js error could affect the slick slider?